# Can I load vulkan extension in more "Cpp-binding-like" way

Tags: c++, vulkan

I'm reading [Vulkan Tutorial](https://vulkan-tutorial.com/Introduction) and want to use Vulkan C++ binding instead. But error occured when I load `vkCreateDebugUtilsMessengerEXT` and `vkDestroyDebugUtilsMessengerEXT`.

Seems like `instance.getProcAddr("extension_name")` won't really load a function into instance object, so I can't directly invoke, for example, `destroyDebugUtilsMessengerEXT` by an object of `vk::Instance` , because `vkDestroyDebugUtilsMessengerEXT` is an unresolved symbol. The demo of Vulkan sdk`cube.cpp` manually defines this function, so that the internal invocation of `destroyDebugUtilsMessengerEXT` can find out a definition of `vkDestroyDebugUtilsMessengerEXT`. But defining a function with same name of built-in function is definitely weird to me.

Also, I know the below is another way to do the same thing.

```cpp
// This is the method in Vulkan Tutorial
// https://vulkan-tutorial.com/code/02_validation_layers.cpp
// Make a wrapper
void DestroyDebugUtilsMessengerEXT(VkInstance instance, VkDebugUtilsMessengerEXT debugMessenger, const VkAllocationCallbacks* pAllocator) {
    auto func = (PFN_vkDestroyDebugUtilsMessengerEXT) vkGetInstanceProcAddr(instance, "vkDestroyDebugUtilsMessengerEXT");
    if (func != nullptr) {
        func(instance, debugMessenger, pAllocator);
    }
}

// And call it in cleanup()
DestroyDebugUtilsMessengerEXT(instance, debugMessenger, nullptr);
```

Could I have a neat way to load those functions without defining a function having same name of built-in or calling them by ugly C style code?

Comment: If by "directly invoke", you mean `object.member_function()`... yes, you cannot *dynamically* add members to a type (or object) in C++. There is nothing un-C++-like about using non-member functions to operate on an object.

Comment: You're either going to need a wrapper function or a function pointer which you'll have to check for null yourself. There is no way around that as Vulkan relies on dynamically importing all functions from the ICD.

Comment: @NicolBolas I'm ok with using non-member function on an object. The weird thing is `vulkan.hpp` provides member functions, like `(create/destroy)DebugUtilsMessengerEXT`, but can not be invoked because its internal function can not be linked. All I want is ensuring if "defining the internal function is exactly what I should do and what I should get used to". Such thing is really unusual to me but is exactly what the official demo shows me.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out how to dynamically load functions without mixed code style by myself. I couldn't find those corresponding functions because `vulkan.hpp` is too large and Intellisense in vscode is too slow.

For the case in my question, I should use `instance.createDebugUtilsMessengerEXT(vk::DebugUtilsMessengerCreateInfoEXT)`. The last parameter of this function has a default value which assign a default dynamic loader for it.

Vulkan C++ binding has provided all those stuff as member function. The rule is : the invoking object is always the type of the first parameter of original function. For example, the first parameter of `vkDestroyDebugUtilsMessengerEXT` is `VkInstance`, hence the caller object is of type `vk::Instance`. The first parameter of `vkCreateRenderPass` is `VkDevice`, so the caller object is of type `vk::Device`.

That's all. For a beginner, it's no need to consider too much about loader, the default loader has handled all troubles for us.

One last thing: if Intellisense is too slow/stupid to load correct result, you can search the corresponding wrapper class within `vulkan_structs.hpp` and `vulkan_funcs.hpp`. This helped me a lot.